# Groovy library in android

Tags: java, android, groovy

Please help me guys I'm stuck on this problem for over a week.

I'm working on an app which involves groovy. The app simply creates a pdf document with some information.

The part where the pdf is created is written in groovy. I wrote a small groovy library which takes some information and create a pdf document using pdfbox. This library was developed in IntelliJ IDEA and it works perfectly.

Now, the problem occurs when I try to integrate this groovy library with my android application. I managed to build an artifact of the groovy library and even import it to the android studio under `libs` folder, but when I try to run the `main` function of groovy library, the app crashes with a `MissingPropertyException`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.silverfix.groovytestapp, PID: 8030
      groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: EMPTY_DOC for class: app.Constants$Paths
      at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1004)
      at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1859)
      at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1835)
      at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3735)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:51)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
      at app.MainClass.initialize(MainClass.groovy:41)
      at app.MainClass.main(MainClass.groovy:32)
      at com.silverfix.groovytestapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:24)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Code for main class of the groovy library:

```
package app

import app.components.Evaluator
import app.components.FieldRenamer
import app.components.FormMetaHolder
import app.components.FieldPopulater
import app.components.entities.DGObject
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationWidget
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField


/**
 * Created by David on 26/09/2016.
 */
class MainClass {

    static PDDocument document = new PDDocument()

    static void main(args) {
        initialize()
        initiateData()
        initiatePdf()
        populateData()
        saveDocuemnt()
    }

    // Initialize the document's meta data
    static void initialize() {
        InputStream inputStream = MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("$Constants.Paths.EMPTY_DOC")

        PDDocument tempDoc = new PDDocument().load(inputStream)

    }

    static void initiatePdf() {
        ...
    }

    static void initiateData() {
        ...
    }

    static void populateData() {
        ...
    }

    static void saveDocuemnt() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Code for Constants class:
package app

/**
 * Created by David on 09/10/2016.
 */

```
class Constants {

    // Paths
    public static class Paths {
        public static final String RESULT_FILE = "intellijPDF.pdf"
        public static final String EMPTY_DOC = "dgc_empty.pdf"
        public static final String IATA_DOC = "dgc_iata.pdf"
        public static final String SILVER_DOC = "dgc_silverfix.pdf"
    }
}
```

And this is the MainActivity:

```
package com.silverfix.groovytestapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import app.MainClass;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_doc);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MainClass.main(null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Image of the Project hierarchy

[image: Image of the Project hierarchy]

Answer (score 0):

add @CompileStatic try again.

@CompileStatic
public class MainClass {

Answer (score -1):

To use Groovy library in Android project it is necessary to configure Groovy support for Android: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin

After applying Groovy plugin to Android you can add your library as follows (assuming it is in libs directory):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy'
    }
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.12:grooid'
    ...
}
```